# R - Convert strings to dates

Tags: r, string, date

I have a list of dates stored as strings and I'd like to convert them to date format. I face two main problems:

1. The month-day-year separator is not consistent: sometimes it's `_`, sometimes `-`.
2. The month and day positions in the strings are not consistent: sometimes the day comes before the month and sometimes the other way around.

I wonder if there's a way to write the `regex` so that all three strings below are converted to dates.

```
> mydate <- c('Jan_30_2018','April_3-2018','07_June_2018')
> as.Date(mydate,'%B_%d_%Y')
[1] "2018-01-30" NA           NA          
> as.Date(mydate,'%B.%d.%Y')
[1] NA NA NA
> as.Date(mydate,'%B*%d*%Y')
[1] NA NA NA
> as.Date(mydate,'%B+%d+%Y')
[1] NA NA NA
> as.Date(mydate,'%B_%d-%Y')
[1] NA           "2018-04-03" NA
```

Comment: `anytime::anydate(mydate)`

Comment: seems some great idea given by @rawr with this package. Will check in detail.

Comment: it does seem handy.. But @rawr is it just me, or it slow?  (If that vector was length 10,000, for example), for some reason `anydate(mydate)` is taking a long time to process. On the other hand, if the vector had many more variations than the ones that the OP presented, `anydate()` would be the way to go.

Comment: `anytime::anydate` author here. It's as fast as it can be: Boost Date_Time parser in C++, access is vectorised.  There is no faster method that is as general and powerful (not requiring a format, and working with "weird" ones as these).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted by @rawr in a comment an hour ago, the `anydate()` function from my [anytime package](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=anytime) was made for just this:

- does not require a format string but checks a number of possible and sensible ones
- does not require all elements of a vector to use the same format
- does use vectorised and compiled operations so it is fast

##### Example

```
> anytime::anydate(c('Jan_30_2018','April_3-2018','07_June_2018')) 
[1] "2018-01-30" "2018-04-03" "2018-06-07"   
>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great package. I did notice a couple instances where `anydate()` fails to convert strings to date: e.g. `Sept_8_2018` and `May9_2018`. In the former instance, `Sept` was not recognized as short for `September` (but `Sep` was). In the second instance, I had to insert a separator between `May` and `9` for `anydate()` to work properly.

Comment: Thanks -- I think this has come up before and is (inherently) a limitation of the Boost parser which does not like single digit days.  I gave in a few years and added support for R's parser as an alternate, you could try that (set a flag in the call).  But the upshot is there really are shite formats out there which are _hard_ if not _impossible_ to guestimate correctly. Square peg, round hole.

Answer (score 0):

```
as.Date(ifelse(grepl("^[A-Z]",mydate),
       as.Date(gsub("_","-",mydate), "%B-%d-%Y"),
       as.Date(gsub("_","-",mydate), "%d-%B-%Y")
       ), origin="1970-01-01")

[1] "2018-01-30" "2018-04-03" "2018-06-07"
```

##### Update

This approach provides some nice speed, in case your vector `mydate` is of any reasonable size:

```
library(data.table)

data.table(d=gsub("_","-",mydate))[
, fifelse(grepl("^[A-Za-z]",d),as.Date(d,"%B-%d-%Y"), as.Date(d,"%d-%B-%Y"))]
```